# htaccess url rewrite help

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [PT,L]
```

Now I want to add an exception, that if the URL is something like mysite.com/abc it should ignore it and all things inside it also. mysite.com/abc/dfgs also should be excluded from this rewriting.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If /abc is an existing directory, you can put another .htaccess file in there with

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

If it's really just one string you want to not rewrite (whether it exists or not)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc
```

will not rewrite if the requested path starts with "/abc"

To test rewrite rules without messing up the site for regular browsers (not that you should be editing in a live environment of course, this is purely hypothetical :-) ), I've found the following very helpful:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 12.34.56.78 # <-- where that's your IP address
```

Comment: This helped me. I was having a case where my client had a blog in the root with a funky .htaccess, and then Kayako Support in a support folder. I was able to turn off the .htaccess rules in that folder because the Kayako software was really picky and was throwing up 403 Forbidden errors.

Answer (score 0):

This should avoid rewriting if the URI contains abc. This may or may not be exactly what you want. If it isn't edit your question.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Rewrite ONLY if the REQUEST does NOT contain abc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !abc

# Rewrite all other URLs 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [PT,L]
```