# How to set a URL rewrite for sub-domain links like these?

Tags: php, http, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a site ( say by name `www.manoj.com` ) and I have created a forum on sub-domain

```
forum.manoj.com
```

Now, I want to redirect all the links following `manoj.com/forum/{anything else}` to `forum.manoj.com/{anything else}`

How can I do it.

Thanks

Comment: use .htaccess  see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055281/htaccess-url-rewrite-help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to redirect `example.com/forum` to `forum.example.com`, in `[document_root]/forum/.htaccess` write:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  !=forum.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://forum.example.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

The `R=301` flag is to indicate it is a "permanent" redirect, Apache will send the header `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`.

If you really cannot add a `.htaccess` file there, in `[document_root]/.htaccess` write:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  !=forum.example.com
RewriteRule forum/(.*) http://forum.example.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

But this is not enough. You need to set the DNS record for `forum.example.com` and set up virtual host (if you use Apache) on the server before it will work. Typically virtual hosts are defined in `httpd.conf`. For more see [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: Hi.. I have added a entry in DNS and it is working as well.But the problem is it is working for both http://forum.manoj.com/news/id/2541 and http://manoj.com/forum/news/id/2541... I just want to redirect the url from http://manoj.com/forum/<--- anything like news_id--->  TO http://forum.manoj.com/<--same thing like news_id --->

Comment: @NaanuManu I understand. What you need is in my answer. (and I just modifyed it a bit)

Comment: I dont have a seperate .htaccess for forum... I have NO [document_root]/forum/.htaccess

I want it to include it in web/.htaccess only..

Comment: @NaanuManu If you can't create a `.htaccess` for it you can see my new solution