# How to make same Website as multiple subdomain

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, subdomain

I need a big big help from you guys.
I have a website, say for an example www.abc.com. My Client need to change this entire website for three subdomains to address three countries.all three should be identical copies.

Example:

1. http://us.abc.com
2. http://in.abc.com

All the three subdomains should work like the main website.
I thought to copy all my site folders to copy into three folders as US, IN, FR and uploading it into the host and direct those folders to subdomains. Since this will create large number of files and folders I'll hesitate to do this.

Is this method is good or how should I overcome the situation... Glad if you can give me a clue. Thanks.

Comment: some area can be visible only for specific country. Lets say there is an image need to display only to US not to IN or FR. there is a classified area if someone log in us.abc.com he can only view or add US classifieds only...etc

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11220108/1386111

Comment: Thanks Alvin i checked that...i am not sure that will make sense to my problem...May be i couldn't understand that. i will chek it again..:))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is:

1. It sounds like you want to use Apache virtual hosts (so the different domain names will be handled by the same server):

   - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/
2. Of course, you need to have DNS for the three domains point to your web server
3. You can use Apache configuration to allow the content to be shared or distinguished between the different domains as you wish.

'Hope that helps...

PS:
To answer your original question:

If "http://us.abc.com" and "http://in.abc.com" were different domains with identical content, you wouldn't even need virtual hosts: you could have "abc.com" serve both.  But virtual hosts would still be cleaner - in case you wanted to customize one site or the other in the future.

If, on the other hand, you had "http://mysite.abc.com" and "http://mysite.abc.com.in", then you could *still* serve both sites from the same server.  But you *must* use virtual hosts (because "abc.com" and "abc.com.in" are different domains).

Again - I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot paulsm4. I have gone through your link and felt that can be help to overcome my problem.though i am not a web expert, we are using godaddy hosting plans. i think they do not allow us to modify any configuration(i am not sure). how can i overcome the virtual hosting from a shared server..? sorry if i make you uncomfortable. i asked this because i dont know these stuffs and i really want to do this..:) Thanks again for your answer

Comment: Guys i got a fair solution for what i need, using directing my subdomains to same directory. Everything is going to be fine. But the i got an another problem. because if i do this then my javascripts is not working under subdomains. i have comment area and it woks for the main domina without any problem but for subdomains, not errors but nothing happens(i mean comment area is not functioning as main domain)